# Missing Cocoa Application Template in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode

The 'Cocoa Application' template is missing from Xcode 5. Has anyone else encountered this?
The only options are SpriteKit Game, Cocoa-AppleScript Application, and Command Line Tool.  I tried to post a screenshot, but I don't have the reputation.
According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/ApplicationCreationProcess/ApplicationCreationProcess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH6-997620) it should be an option:
I've googled, but to no avail. I tried reinstalling Xcode but it's still missing. I'm on Mavericks and using Xcode 5.1.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various things including reinstalling xCode, and repairing permissions I created another user account and it did indeed have the cocoa app template in xCode. In the end I reinstalled OS X and xCode and all the templates are there. I'm not sure what the issue with the original user account was but it's all working now. Apologies for not being able to provide a more insightful answer.